# Benefits of updating kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, upgrade

What are benefits of updating kernel ?
On linux mint 18 kde I had updated kernel two times but still I'm getting latest update so though its not recommend I did and so what are benefits of updating kernel ?

Comment: You get to see new bug fixes and new features before other people.  You also get to see new bugs before other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should update the kernel when the system asked you to  do

- **Security Fixes:** close up problems of security that has been discovered. You’ll always be safer with the new kernel.
- **Stability Improvements:** it can improve the stability of the system (exp: the system crash through regular use).
- Increase the speed of the Linux machine and  improve the overall productivity quite a bit.
- Updated Drivers because the new kernel includes the latest open source drivers for devices.

Comment: +1 We have also seen improvements in the network stack.